# Triggering an Event by KeyCombination in javaFX

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, java-8, javafx-8

I am trying to set a shortcut to save a file.

```
public static final KeyCombination saveShortcut = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);
```

I trigger an action by:

```
sceneRoot.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (saveShortcut.match(event)) {
                saveProject.fire();
            } 
        }

    });
```

However, the event gets fired by just hitting the <kbd>S</kbd> key. Any ideas on why so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value for all the modifiers in the `KeyCodeCombination` constructor is `RELEASED`. So your save shortcut matches the key <kbd>S</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd> released, <kbd>Alt</kbd> released, <kbd>Meta</kbd> released, and <kbd>Control</kbd> either pressed or released (the `ANY` value that you specified matches either pressed or released).

If you want this to only match <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> you should use

```
public static final KeyCombination saveShortcut = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
```

Better still is

```
public static final KeyCombination saveShortcut = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);
```

which would match the shortcut key appropriate to the platform (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on Mac).

Comment: Hi James, Thanks. I went with the first one. For the second solution, how would it know that CONTROL is pressed? All it says SHORTCUT_DOWN.

Comment: As I said, it matches Control on windows and Command on Mac; i.e. it matches the appropriate key for a "shortcut" keystroke on the given platform. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html).

Comment: oh ok. So "SHORTCUT_DOWN" is another way of saying Control on Windows, or Command on Mac. I thought it was "shortcut" , as in the way we use it in daily context. Makes sense :)

Comment: What does it do on linux?