# stage from iconified state to regular size via shortcut

Tags: javafx-8

I would like to ask you about possibilities to restore JavaFx 8 app from iconified mode (`setIconified(true)`) to regular size via shortcut for example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>. 
I use Windows 7 and jdk 1.8.0_40 beta.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751657/triggering-an-event-by-keycombination-in-javafx

Answer (score 0):

I know about javafx KeyCombination. After some search I found: [jintellitype](https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/)